# Unable to read error of InfoPath dialog box during publishing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have simple InfoPath form. I saved it and published it successfully.

Then I added C# code to InfoPath form which will populate a text field. Now this required to start Sandbox solution feature on the farm and do I did it.

Now when I try to publish the form i gives me this error-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the error text, launch the Windows' Event Viewer and open Applications and Services -> Microsoft Office Alerts log. You might want to filter by 'Level' not-equal 'Information', filtering is on the right pane of EV.