# Truncated (unreadable) error, Infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, form

Getting the following error image, instead of full image that would / could provide more info, if I could read it.  Has occurred in several different operations, attempts in information retrieval from a SP, Publishing or saving, and more.  Event log not identifying more specifics
Anyone else encountering this?  Is there something simple to remedy to be able to see the whole error and address the issue without guessing?

[image]

Comment: Check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160019/unable-to-read-error-of-infopath-dialog-box-during-publishing/

Answer (score 0):

You may also try a different browser and/or browser version. In IE, press F12 and use the Emulation tab to switch to a different version. Another thing you can do is check the SharePoint Logs on the server. You don't have a correlation ID, but you can check against the date / time and the category will be InfoPath.

Hope this helps!